# What is a formal alternative to verb 'toggle'?

Tags: single-word-requests

For a long time I've been using a word 'toggle' to express change of states (normally button). Now I found out on [Dictionary.com / toggle](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/toggle) that toggle has such meaning in an *informal* language as a verb. Which would be the correct word to express verb for 'change state'?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! This question is too basic and is likely to be closed; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information. For example: http://www.synonyms.net/synonym/toggle

Comment: @Hugo : this is a good question becuase Arturs has been misled by an internet reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionary.com is misleading here. Toggle is the correct technical term. Perhaps they mean it is "informal' to use this technical term in a non-technical context.

cf [merraim webster's defintion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toggle)

Comment: Thanks & thanks for the resource link, I liked it and will definitely use it much during mastering English